# Long press to insert special character/symbol in Windows?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I've just learnt that on Macs, it's possible to long press a key to insert symbols associated with that key (eg A --> ÀÁÂÃÄÅ).

Is it possible to emulate this behaviour on a Windows machine?
If software-specific, I'd like it to work in Word, if not the entire Office suite.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry i can't name a free solution, but:

1) HoldKey - does exactly what you want. They have a demo video online, check their site: http://www.holdkey.eu

As that's a single-use application, with little to no configuration possibilities - here is another:

2) Key Manager - a multi-purpose keyboard and mouse configuration tool. Your long-press-sequence will not work out of the box, it's not as convenient and easy to use as the first one. You'd have to config a lot of stuff. Pro is: you can config lots of stuff. Almost anything you want to do with keyboard or mouse can be configured there. But it can take some time to get a solid working configuration done. Their site: https://atnsoft.com/keymanager - and some info about long-press using this tool: https://www.ghacks.net/2018/05/07/add-long-tap-keyboard-functionality-to-windows/

(Last site also provides further links about special character input methods.)

The only free solution i have in mind would be a script using AutoIt, but that requires a little programming by yourself - i don't know if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Word or Office usage, the easiest solution is to use keyboard shortcuts as described [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000657.htm).

Use the CTRL key plus the accent you want, followed by the letter.  Some quick ones:

```
Desired Symbol                      Shortcut Key Combination
à, è, ì, ò, ù, À, È, Ì, Ò, Ù        Ctrl+` (accent grave), the letter
á, é, í, ó, ú, ý, Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ý  Ctrl+' (apostrophe), the letter
â, ê, î, ô, û, Â, Ê, Î, Ô, Û        Ctrl+Shift+^ (caret), the letter
ã, ñ, õ, Ã, Ñ, Õ                    Ctrl+Shift+~ (tilde), the letter
ä, ë, ï, ö, ü, ÿ, Ä, Ë, Ï, Ö, Ü, Ÿ  Ctrl+Shift+: (colon), the letter
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this free tool that has worked for me when switching from macos to windows 10. The tool is called AX Windows and can be found here: http://vulpeculox.net/ax/

Here is a screenshot showing how it works:

[image: Screenshot: how it works]